# Connection between Oracle 10g and Android

Tags: android, oracle, oracle10g

i have a database in my laptop. i want to access it from an **android** application. since i am new in this field, i don't have a least idea about connection android with oracle. please suggest me how to do it?

i am using **oracle 10g express edition**. i want to retrieve a table data to my android app from my database.

please give me the codes that i will need to perform this task.

what files do i need to perform the connection.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should put a rest or soap service in front of your rdbms and let your mobile app communicate with it.

For php webservice (on a windows based machine) you can setup xampp with php oci8 drivers and oracle instant client.
You can use http post or get method from your android app to transfer data from your app to your webservice and vice versa. You can execute your sql queries from your php script(webservice).

If you don't want to build up you're own web service, then you can use oracle database mobile server
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need  simple java util see attach 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: i wanted to know about the android and oracle 10g connection not about oracle and java in host machine connection